# What does this javascript code mean and how to i decode it using php

Tags: php, javascript, url, decode

this code has a URL in it, how do i use php to decode the url out of it:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' > eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
   while(c--)if(k[c])p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + c.toString(a) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]); return p}
('1l.1k(\'<7 13="1j"1i="1h:1g-1f-1e-1d-1c"p="o"n="m"1b="3://b.5.a/9/1a.19"><2 1="t"0="s"/><2 1="r"0="q"/><2 1="6"0="3://i/l/k.j"/><2 1="f"0="4"><2 1="g"0="4"/><2 1="e"0="c"/><2 1="h"0="4"/><2 1="12"0="3://11.10.z.y:x/d/w/v.u"/><8 13="18"17="16/5"12="3://11.10.z.y:x/d/w/v.u"t="s"r="q"p="o"n="m"6="3://i/l/k.j"h="4"g="4"6=""f="4"e="c"15="3://b.5.a/9/14/"></8></7>\');', 36, 58, 'value|name|param|http|false|divx|previewImage|object|embed|plugin|com|go|Play||previewMessage|allowContextMenu|bannerEnabled|autoPlay||jpg|212fw9jbfz7i|00009|318|height|640|width|transparent|wmode|Stage6|custommode|avi|qdnonvmiasgyh|zvq6lstdylqvn6lrwin6bli5reamli6ry5ewvwlk5mpa|182|51|73|90|66|src|id|download|pluginspage|video|type|np_vid|cab|DivXBrowserPlugin|codebase|CC0F21721616|9C46|41fa|D0AB|67DABFBF|clsid|classid|ie_vid|write|document'.split('|')))
```

If you could help that would be great !

Comment: Please use the code formatting.

Comment: Looks like it is designed to be hard to read—a dubious security technique known as obfuscation.

Comment: @Gazler, I think the point is that the code is obfuscated

Comment: I think it decodes to "4 8 15 16 23 42".

Comment: Wow. javascript compression. I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 3):

It has been compressed using [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/). [This page](http://www.red-root.com/code/decompressing-packed-javascript-files/) explains how to unpack it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org) this unpacks to:

`document.write('<object id="ie_vid"classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616"width="640"height="318"codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab"><param name="custommode"value="Stage6"/><param name="wmode"value="transparent"/><param name="previewImage"value="http://i/00009/212fw9jbfz7i.jpg"/><param name="allowContextMenu"value="false"><param name="bannerEnabled"value="false"/><param name="previewMessage"value="Play"/><param name="autoPlay"value="false"/><param name="src"value="http://66.90.73.51:182/d/zvq6lstdylqvn6lrwin6bli5reamli6ry5ewvwlk5mpa/qdnonvmiasgyh.avi"/><embed id="np_vid"type="video/divx"src="http://66.90.73.51:182/d/zvq6lstdylqvn6lrwin6bli5reamli6ry5ewvwlk5mpa/qdnonvmiasgyh.avi"custommode="Stage6"wmode="transparent"width="640"height="318"previewImage="http://i/00009/212fw9jbfz7i.jpg"autoPlay="false"bannerEnabled="false"previewImage=""allowContextMenu="false"previewMessage="Play"pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/"></embed></object>')`

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is obfuscated code. You can try figuring out what parameters are being passed into it (maybe by using Firebug and that Javascript debugger) and then get the return value out of it. But obfuscated code is called obfuscated for a reason :).